# Remove rtf formatting from string

Tags: c++, string, format, rtf, remove-if

I need to subtract text from string with rtf format.

I have a string in rtf format

```cpp
std::wstring sString= L"{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\nouicompat\\deflang2057{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fprq12\\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}\r\n{\\*\\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\\viewkind4\\uc1 \r\n\\pard\\f0\\fs24 HELLO\\par\r\n}\r\n"
```

How can I get a string "HELLO" from variable sString?

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Comment: You either use an RTF-parsing library or write your own. Writing your own will take a long time.

Comment: Indeed not easy. Specs are quite fat: <https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/Archive_References/%5bMSFT-RTF%5d.pdf>

Comment: @PaulSanders, Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows (and assuming you're not looking for a cross-platform solution), there is a way to do this without using any external libraries.  What you do is:

1. Create an invisible [`RICHEDIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/rich-edit-controls) child window.  Since this should be a child window, it does need a valid parent but it doesn't matter much what.
2. Send it an [`EM_STREAMIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-streamin) message with the `SF_RTF` flag set to load up your RTF.  The data is actually requested from a callback function, so a bit of trickery will be needed there.
3. Send it an [`EM_STREAMOUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-streamout) message with the `SF_TEXT` flag set to retrieve the corresponding plain text.  This will call your designated callback function repeatedly until there is nothing more to retrieve, so you'll probably want to append the data to a `std::string` or similar each time through.
4. Destroy the window you created at step 1 (or you can keep it kicking around, if you plan to re-use it).

It's a bit fiddly to get it all right, but it's not that difficult.  Be prepared to do a bit of background reading.